# Changing encoding python 3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cp1251

Have a default encoding of `'cp1251'`-how can it be changed to `UTF-8` by default in Python3? Because the function sys.setdefaultencoding() is not working

Comment: why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: cause I' m using urllib.request which gives me wrong characters when parsing cyrillic (\xd0\x9e \xd0\x9a\xd0)

Comment: So encode/decode it properly.. Also see [this](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - Try using Requests library which automatically decodes the request to Unicode strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3's `str` is aways in unicode. If you are working with bytearray then

```
mystring = b'my cp1251 byte array'.decode('cp1251')
```

You can keep it as a `str` or put it into utf-8 byte array:

```
my_utf_8_bytearray =  mystring.encode()
```